# How to use custom Logstash grok patterns?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I'm using Logstash on Debian 9 and I want to use custom grok patterns. So I've added them to directory `/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.1.2/patterns` - created new files and also modified existing (grok-patterns, auth, etc.).

Problem is that my changes in original files was overwritten and lost (at 02:35 a.m. 12.6.2018).

Is there some automatic updating of `logstash-patterns-core`? How can I change existing grok patterns?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the directory structure where you modified the file is for binaries. You don't need to modify any files at all to add custom patterns. 
Please have a look at [Logstash Directory layout here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/dir-layout.html#deb-layout).

Instead of modifying or adding files under a binary path, you can create a new directory under `/etc/logstash`, call it a `pattern` and add your custom patterns there.

You can then import custom patterns as follows,

```
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => "../patterns"
        match =>["message", "%{ANYPATTERN}" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to override original pattern, is it possible this way?
And is it possible to specify patterns_dir only once (I use many grok sections)? Thanks!

Comment: that is correct, custom pattern takes priority over default pattern. So, if you have a pattern in core directory and a custom directory, one in the custom directory will be applied. Hence there is no need to modify your default patterns at all.

Comment: you also need to define patterns_dir, everytime you use `grok` filter